# Twilio Token.ToJwt() causes ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException

Tags: jwt, twilio, token, twilio-conversations

I am using Twilio Conversation and generating JWT for token.

When calling `new Twilio.Jwt.AccessToken(/*parameters*/).ToJwt()` method, it causes

```
'token.ToJwt()' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147024809
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: cty"
    ParamName: null
    Source: "System.Private.CoreLib"
    StackTrace: "   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException[T](T key)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)\r\n   at Twilio.Jwt.BaseJwt.ToJwt()"
    TargetSite: {Void ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException[T](T)}
```

Why this causes?

Answer (score 1):

**Keep [Microsoft.Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) version is same or below 4.30.0.**
My case was that It stopped throwing the exception after that.

This error happens once you install Microsoft.Graph with version *above 4.31.0*. Apparently either [Microsoft.Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) or [Twilio](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) nuget packages need to be fixed.

Comment: In my case I also had to update the [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/) NuGet package